# PHP (int) converts MySQL MAX result to 1, no matter what number

Tags: php, mysql

In my table I have a column, `corder`, that's an `int(3)`.

Using `PDO` I run the following:

```
$maxCorder = "SELECT MAX(`corder`) FROM cats WHERE `user` = :uid AND `cparent` = :cp"; 
            $database->query($maxCorder);
            $database->bind(':uid', $_SESSION['userid']);
            $database->bind(':cp', $catID);
            $maxCorderResult = $database->single();
```

and find that if I echo out `$maxCorderResult`, it's the correct max value of the column. I want to add 1 to it, so convert it to an int:

```
$maxCorderResult = (int)$database->single();
```

And find that `$maxCorderResult` is now an `int` of 1. The same applies to `(float)`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Researching it seems to only find an unrelated issue where the number is to large to be converted to an integer and produces unpredictable results. For this test, I only have 4 rows with a `corder` of 0,1,2 and 3. I've manually changed these to various integers and the same results happen.

I'm using a custom PDO class as detailed [here](http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/). The `single()` method calls the following function in the class:

```
public function single(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

---

### Update:

As helpfully pointed out by a few, I foolishly overlooked essential familiarity with what the `PDO` class I was using was actually returning. It was an `array`, not an `int` or a `string`, which is always going to go down badly with trying to cast it to an `int` directly.

I've hopefully learned my lesson to not by distractions such as getting the result I wanted up until the point of conversion (still don't understand how I did), and to triple-check what's being returned in the docs.

Comment: What is the value prior to conversion?

Comment: `:cp` != `:sp`.

Comment: @Fred , good spot. That isn't the var name I used in the actual code, where they are the same. That was a typo for this question that I've corrected now.

Comment: wheres the `execute` part ?

Comment: `single()` is not a builtin PDO method. Are you positively sure it returns the first column of the first row?

Comment: @tadman echo returns 3, or 7 if I change the `corder` column of that row to 7. My testing results show nothing strange about the `query` working. I output the result using `<script>console.log('" . $maxCorderResult . "' );</script>";` and get the expected value in `console`. Converting it to `(int)` or `(float)` outputs 1 to the `console`.

Comment: Apologies, I began using `PDO` with a custom class and sometimes forget I'm using it and didn't mention so in the question. Updated to explain.

Comment: JFYI: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: @YourCommonSense A point well made that I'm guilty of. Seems that I overlooked that I was returning an array. I was confused by the correct result I wanted being echoed (somehow?) until conversion, but it doesn't excuse my lack of familiarity with what I was returning using the class I was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> `PDOStatement::fetch` — Fetches the next **row** from a result set
>
> - fetch_style
>
>   Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This value
>     must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants, defaulting to value of
>     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH).
>
>   `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`: **returns an array** indexed by column name as
>     returned in your result set
> - Return Values
>
>   The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch
>     type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.

It doesn't make any sense to cast a array to int.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It was a silly rookie mistake on my part, I was thrown by getting the correct value echoed back to me until I tried to convert it - it threw me off the trail of seeing it was an array - but I should have been more familiar with what the class I was using was returning rather than assuming. It was that, rather than knowingly casting an array to an int.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand why would someone use such a homemade surrogate if with vanilla PDO it can be done much simpler:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(`corder`) FROM cats WHERE `user` = ? AND `cparent` = ?"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_SESSION['userid'], $catID]);
$maxCorderResult = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: It was actually the clarity of the comments on the class that drew me to it as someone brand new to `PDO` and who couldn't appreciate the scope of it just yet. I don't have a programming background and often find that people in any industry can be blind to what's obvious when beginning and what's not (my own included). After a day of switching my app's functions and calls to `PDO` it was the first explanation/method where I felt comfortable getting everything to work. I'm sure I'll move on from it.